# How do I get a UITextField input as an Integer

Tags: swift, input, uitextfield

I would like to get a `UITextField` input as an Integer? I tried `Int(UITextField Input)`, but it throws an error. I also tried making a variable with the same value, but it did not work.

Comment: `it throws an error` is useless information if you don't tell *which* error you got. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you define like this -> 
`@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!` 
you can use `(textField.text! as NSString).intValue` or `Int(textField.text!)` . You must use exclamation mark.

But you define like this ->

`let textField = UITextField()
 textField.text = "007"`

you don't need use exclamation mark

EDIT:

> `(textField.text! as NSString).intValue` is INT32 Format, you can do this for normal Int format -> `Int((textField.text! as NSString).intValue)`

Comment: I would like to add the numbers, I am new to swift, and am making a simple calculator app.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much this I guess?

```
 self.yourTextField.keyboardType = .NumberPad
```

This will only allow numbers. You will have to expand on your question for more details

Comment: It says: `Expected Declaration`

Comment: you need to show how you are using the above code. then I can help